# How can one call metamask from one's own custom chrome extension?

Tags: metamask, browsers

I'm building a Chrome extension which is supposed to able able:

a) insert custom button on a website, depending on some condtion

b) a button will have to invoke MetaMask, or any other browser-based wallet. But primarilty MetaMask

c) pass some data to it -- "an amount of a payment required for a user to pay"

How can a browser extension activate MetaMask? If at all.

Otherwise, what would be other options?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is content scripts (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts). They're part of your extension build and can be injected into web pages.

Comment: you haven't answered my question

Comment: from a content script you could access the api exposed by wallets like metamask under `window.ethereum`